# How can I toggle the text displayed on a expand and collapse section?

Tags: jquery, html

I was able to pull together a script to expand and collapse a section based a header styles using pieces of code from multiple different sites.

I am now trying to figure out how to make it so so the headers toggle between having a right arrowhead in front of the header text when collapsed, and a down arrow head when expanded.

HTML Code for Right Arrowhead: `&#10148;` ➤

HTML Code for down arrow head: `&#9660;` ▼

I am just getting my feet wet in terms of HTML code so any assistance/ideas are greatly appreciated.

Here is the script I have so far for expanding and collapsing.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('h2').css('cursor','pointer');
     $("h2").nextUntil("h2").slideToggle();
     $("h2").click(function() {$(this).nextUntil("h2").slideToggle();});
     });
</script><div style="position:relative;">
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('h4').css('cursor','pointer');
     $("h4").nextUntil("h4").slideToggle();
     $("h4").click(function() {$(this).nextUntil("h4").slideToggle();});
 });
</script><div style="position:relative;">
```

Here is the HTML Code where the headers and associated text are where it callaspes and expands based on the script above

```
    <div class="MainBody">
    <div class="ContentArea">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-3 StickyParent">
                <div id="mySticky" class="pageToc fixedsticky top ">
                    <div class="Toc_1">
                        Help</div>
                    <div class="Toc_2">
                        <a href="#ch1">Contact My SourceToPay Connect</a></div>
                    <div class="Toc_2"> 
                        <a href="#ch2">FAQ’s</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-9 ">
                <h1 class="NoTopSpace">Help</h1>
                <img alt="Help image" class="roundA " src="CargillHelp1.jpg" />
                <h2 name="ch1" id="ch1" class="aLink"> ➤ Contact My SourceToPay Connect</h2>
                <p>Please use the request form at the below link to submit your question, comments, feedback, or request to My SourceToPay  Connect.
                </p>
                <p>
                <a class="button" href="https://cargillonline.sharepoint.com/sites/ProcureToPay/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId=%7B046A619E%2D7998%2D4406%2DB93A%2D4007FAC5726A%7D&amp;RootFolder=">
                My SourrceToPay Connect Contact Form </a></p>
                <h2 name="ch2" id="ch2" class="aLink">FAQ’s</h2>
                <p>COMING SOON</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row spaceBottom ">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/f69nz7t4/2/

Comment: I would strongly suggest altering your HTML structure to make this considerably easier. Wrapping the arrow in its own `span` with its own class would let you target that bit. Similarly, wrapping the section being expanded/collapsed in its own `div` would likewise make it easier to select.

Answer (score 1):

@Mike McCaughan provides a a better answer / suggestion in his comment:

> I would strongly suggest altering your HTML structure to make this
>   considerably easier. Wrapping the arrow in its own span with its own
>   class would let you target that bit[...]

And, @Daniel D's solution is a more elegant one using css class `.rotate {}`

However, if you are hell-bent on using a text-replace strategy as outlined in your question...

```js
$('#ch1').on('click', function() {
  var header_text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(header_text.replace('➤', '▼'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 name="ch1" id="ch1" class="aLink"> &#10148 Contact My SourceToPay Connect</h2>
```

Which can obviously be improved through some of the jquery animation functions. You'll also need to include some "toggle logic"

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as `.toggleClass`. And the class you toggle to has rotation. Then it would also be the same arrow and not two different.

*I would append the `cursor: pointer` to the css, as it is consistent.*

Here is the jQuery idea:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".aLink").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('rotate90deg');
            $(this).toggleClass('rotatedefault');
            $(".the-class-of-the-area-you-want-to-toggle").slideToggle(300);
        });
    });
```

aLink already has the rotatedefault class. `class="aLink rotatedefault"`

and the you can create the rotate90deg class in your css with the rotation, and you could even put some transition on it, if you would want some effect.